# Not working autocomplete django rest framework in visual studio code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been looking for a solution for a very long time. Decided to post this so as not to lose this solution.

Answer (score 1):

We need to add this code to settings.json

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
"python.analysis.indexing": true,
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths":[["rest_framework", 5, true]],
```

If necessary, you can increase the search depth.
Taken from here https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2312